# Right Shift not working in inline assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly, yul

I working on in-line assembly in the smart contract.

```
function rightShift(uint256 x) public pure returns (uint256 result) {
       assembly {
          result := shr(x,1)
       }
    }
```

Above function always return zero. Am I doing something wrong or it’s bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always double-check the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/yul.html#evm-dialect).

> shr(x, y) logical shift right y by x bits

With your notation, you are effectively shifting `1` by `x` bits to the right. For any non-zero value, the result will be zero.

You probably meant to write :

```
function rightShift(uint256 x) public pure returns (uint256 result) {
   assembly {
      result := shr(1,x)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at the [definition](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/yul.html?highlight=evm%20dialect#evm-dialect) of the `shr` Yul instruction:

> shr(x, y): logical shift right `y` by `x` bits

Your function always returns 0 because you are shifting by `x` (your variable `x`) bits, not by 1 bit.

To make it work, you have to rewrite it like this:

```
function rightShift(uint256 x) public pure returns (uint256 result) {
    assembly {
        result := shr(1, x)
    }
}
```